# Parsing JSON without Object Mapping in Restkit iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, restkit

I've created a login page which uses Restkit `RKClient` to send login details, and get back JSON data (either the user or an error). I want to be able to parse the JSON data without object mapping, just JSON to dictionary. The reason for this is it's just a simple login thats sending username and password, if I set up object mapping, i'll have to set up the login details into a Login object, then set up routing etc... and it seem a bit long winded.

Here is my code

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.username.text forKey:@"username"];
    [params setObject:self.password.text forKey:@"password"];
    [params setObject:@"login" forKey:@"type"];
    [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/login" params:params delegate:self];

}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response {
    if ([request isPOST]) {
        if ([response isJSON]) {
            NSLog(@"Got a JSON response back from our POST: %@", response.bodyAsString);
        }
    }

    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

}
```

How can I get the JSON data to a readable object? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply call parsedBody:nil on your RKResponse object and assign the returned object to an NSDictionary:

```
responseDict = [response parsedBody:nil];
```

And as an extra check I use a little convenience method to check for a a successful response:

```
- (bool) wasRequestSuccessfulWithResponse:(RKResponse*)response {

    bool isSuccessfulResponse = NO; 

    id parsedResponse;

    NSDictionary *responseDict;

    if(response != nil) {

        parsedResponse = [response parsedBody:nil];

        if ([parsedResponse isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

            responseDict = [response parsedBody:nil];

            if([[responseDict objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue]) {

                isSuccessfulResponse = YES;
            }
        }

    } 

    return isSuccessfulResponse;

}
```

Comment: How can I do this in RestKit 0.2 because there is no RKResponse class anymore

Comment: I have the same question... confuse the kit can do complex job but some time we just need simply directly got the response as dictionary but class

Comment: if you want the response as an object use the RKObjectManager https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 5.1+ there's NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: how can i use NSJSONSerialization ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using RestKit 0.2 and NSJSONSerialization:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:kLoginURL
                                       parameters:params
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                              NSError *error;
                                              NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
                                              NSLog(@"msg: %@", [json objectForKey:@"msg"]);
                                          }
                                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                          }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an open source library like [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) for that. It is able to parse a JSON response into a NSDictionary or NSArray.