# RestKit - Request without object mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am integrating RestKit with my project. I am using the version **RestKit-0.20.2**. Is there any way we can do the requests without object mapping in this version? I want to do the same thing the poster does here: [Parsing JSON without Object Mapping in Restkit iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054334/parsing-json-without-object-mapping-in-restkit-ios). But it seems its a old version, and RKClient is not available in 0.20.2.

Is it possible to do request without object mapping using RestKit-0.20.2?

P.S.: I searched in Google and I could not be able to find/recognize the correct answer for my question as I am new to RestKit.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why not use the underlying AFNetworking classes?

Comment: Great. I think AFNetworking will help me. Thanks a lot. You would like to post this as an answer? Or do you think we should delete this post? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: As there was a question about the previous version of RestKit too it seems reasonable that this one should stay here and have an actual answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RestKit uses `AFNetworking` to perform all of its raw network communication and builds mapping on top. So, if you need to make requests without mapping you have full access to the `AFNetworking` classes to do so.

Comment: I want to do some code between mapping and response. I want mapping and network request both, but separately. Want to give response as input to Restkit for mapping. Any idea

Comment: @AmitBattan, I don't understand you comment. You probably want to raise a question with full details.

Comment: You can get the `AFHTTPClient` inside the manager this way:

    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:url];
    AFHTTPClient* client = manager.HTTPClient;

Answer (score 2):

I needed to send a PUT without object (and with Basic authorization). After trying different approaches, I finally sent the request using `AFHTTPClient` directly:

```
AFHTTPClient* client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://the.host"]];
[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:username password:password];
[client putPath:@"/api/resource" parameters:nil success:success failure:failure];
```