# Restkit how to map arbitrary json (keys may change overtime) to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, rest, restkit

Let's say that in response to a `PUT` request:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]
    putObject:nil
    path:@"/api/users/add-user"
    parameters:dictionary
    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }
    failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"Failure");
    }
];
```

I get a "*JSON*" of unknown structure. I don't know what and how many keys to expect, but the values are all strings. How do I map it to a `NSDictionary *object`?

Comment: Uh, you parse it with NSJSONSerialization.  Is there something about that that you don't understand?

Comment: What exactly do I parse?

Comment: The JSON string that you "got".

Comment: Which is in which variable?

Comment: Although, looking at the RK stuff, it appears that "mappingResult" may already contain the (thinly veiled) dictionary.  So you're done.  Just look at the dictionary to see what's there.

Comment: (You said "I get a 'JSON' of unknown structure", which implies that you got something somehow.  I never use RestKit, so you know it better than I do and presumably know where you're "getting" stuff.)

Comment: mappingResult will contain the parsed dictionary only if a correct response descriptor is defined before sending a put request. In this case I can't provide a response descriptor, because I don't know what response to expect.

Comment: Seems like a defect in the design of RestKit, eh?

Comment: There must be a way out.

Comment: What do you mean the JSON is of an unknown structure? RK can't map to dynamic JSON. You need some sort of API contract between the client and the server. With that contract in place, you can draw up a mapping for it.

Comment: Consider that the "contract" is for an NSDictionary.

Comment: Or refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054334/parsing-json-without-object-mapping-in-restkit-ios).

Comment: @ZviBar If you wanted the raw `NSDictionary` Then a `[mappingResult dictionary]` will give you what you need. from there you can loop through the dictionary keys and get it's corresponding values.

Comment: @Steve - this is exactly what I need. I'll try that when I'm back at work tommorow. Thank you.

Comment: RestKit doesn't work like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a REST client to see the response and the structure of the JSON response, and create a corresponding model to map it against. Or if this is something that is not a consistent model, you can use NSJSONSerialization to parse the JSON into a KV pair, and your variable of interest in 'mappingResult'.

And you might want to look in AFNetworking 2.0. It works very well with your REST calls and parsing your JSON. 
http://nshipster.com/afnetworking-2/

Comment: How do I use 'NSJSONSerialization' with `- (void)putObject:(id)object path:(NSString *)path parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(void ( ^ ) ( RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , RKMappingResult *mappingResult ))success failure:(void ( ^ ) ( RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error ))failure` method

Comment: In your success block, you are getting the mappingResult of type RKMappingResult. You should see what is the structure of your response and then see if you even have to do the serialization or not. Look at http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKMappingResult.html

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand what RKMappingResult really is about.

Answer (score 1):

If the JSON response has an unknown structure then you either shouldn't be using RestKit (just use `NSJSONSerialization` and handle everything yourself) or you will need to use an [`RKDynamicMapping`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKDynamicMapping.html) so that you can analyse the incoming data and decide what mapping to create (on-the-fly) and return to action the processing.